# PyInstaller lib not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, tkinter, pyinstaller

I made a simple python[3.5.2] program using tkinter. When I use pyinstaller[3.2] on it it gives me a ton of 'lib not found' warnings.
Example:

> 2999 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python\python.exe
>
> 3031 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   c:\python\python.exe
>
> 3218 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python\VCRUNTIME140.dll
>
> 3312 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python\VCRUNTIME140.dll
>
> 6494 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python\DLLs_hashlib.pyd
>
> 7271 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd

.bat file I use to make executables is

> @echo off
>
> set /p file_name="Enter file name: "
>
> pyinstaller %0..\%file_name%\%file_name%.py --onefile --windowed --distpath %0..\%file_name% --name=%file_name%
>
> del %file_name%.spec
>
> rmdir /s /q build
>
> echo.
>
> pause

What am I doing wrong?
Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 4):

Just had this problem myself. The problem is that pyinstaller is not fully compatible Windows 10. The only solution currently is to download the Windows 10 SDK (a 2GB download).

See more here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1566

Comment: but then do what, can you be explicit, add something to pathex? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416221/pyinstaller-distributing-opencv-from-windows-10-to-windows-10-ucrt-dlls

Comment: Worth noting that according to github link provided, these error messages are harmless

Answer (score 1):

I answered a question with a similar solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56942695/10951987

When there is a whole slew of WARNINGS coming from pyinstaller about not being able to locate Windows DLLs, you might check to see if they're in one of the two following locations:

```
C:\Windows\System32\downlevel
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\downlevel
```

You can add one or both to the PATH variable, like so and those warnings should disappear:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32\downlevel
```

I noticed some of the DLLs you're unable to locate are in the folders I called out above.

Note: this will work for any DLLs that you can track down on your machine.  Add that directory to PATH so that pyinstaller can find them.