# Pyinstaller distributing opencv from Windows 10 to Windows <10, missing ucrt dlls api-ms-win-crt

Tags: python, windows, opencv, pyinstaller

I have a Python 3.5 64 bit program (required by tensorflow for Windows) that uses OpenCV. I am distributing it with pyinstaller.

I built my program with Windows 10

```
/c/Python35/Scripts/pyinstaller -c DeepMeerkat.spec
```

On my computer, the .exe builds and runs perfectly. On any other non-Windows 10 machine

On

```
import cv2
```

Returns

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I can see a huge amount of discussion on this on [pyInstaller thread](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1566),
but I can't quite tell how to put it into practice. Dependency walker says I'm missing a number of DLLs

```
api-ms-win-crt-**.dll
```

Okay, from the pyInstaller threads, I know that these DLLs exist

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs
```

Under multiple subfolders base on architecture.

I tried adding to my .spec file

```
pathex=["C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Redist/ucrt/DLLs/"],
```

Or for my particular architecture

```
pathex=["C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Redist/ucrt/DLLs/arm"],
```

Which is what I thought was being suggested [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/38721ef440344d416e26bbaa91a0acb23d0bf948/doc/usage.rst)

> "Install the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10 and
>   expand the .spec-file to include the required DLLs, see “Distributing
>   Software that uses the Universal CRT“ in the above-mentioned link,
>   number 6."

That did not have any effect. I am getting hundreds of errors like

```
121472 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python35\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
```

But I can see that DLL here

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\arm
```

[image]

So then I literally copied posthoc the entire folder

```
cp -r "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Redist/ucrt/DLLs/" dist/Lib/
```

But it's not clear how to connect these to the `.exe`. Clearly, letting pyInstaller know beforehand is preferable.

I also tried

```
/c/Python35/Scripts/pyinstaller --path "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Redist/ucrt/DLLs/arm" -c DeepMeerkat.spec
```

And it still did not find them

I've also tried adding that folder to PATH. Any ideas?

Comment: I was unable to make this work, even after finding the dlls. The "solution" was to just use my installer to install vcredist_x86.exe on the user's machine, this solved it, even though they appear identical. Perhaps a PATH issue on the user's machine.

Comment: Which version of PyInstaller are you using? Version 3.3 released last month fixed a number for Python >=3.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: I was using the dev branch on github as instructed by the maintainers.

Answer (score 3):

If you would have provided your spec file I'd could see what's going on. From here its likely your not including files.

There is two methods to go from here:

1. Create "one" single file that includes all dll's, pyd files and more... a large exe-file as result.
2. The other way is to have it as file + folder filled with dll files, etc... you get a small exe-file.

Check [add binary (incl. dll) files here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-binary-files) the pyinstaller documentation about including files manually.

Check [add data files here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) the pyinstaller documentation about including files manually.

An example spec-file that includes dll files from your dll folder.

`block_cipher = None
     a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
                  pathex        = ['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
                  binaries      = [ ( 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs', '.' ) ],
                  datas         = [ ('helpmod/help_data.txt', 'helpmod' ) ],
                  hiddenimports = [],
                  hookspath     = None,
                  runtime_hooks = None,
                  excludes      = None,
                  cipher        = block_cipher)
     pyz  = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher = block_cipher)
     exe  = EXE(pyz,... )
     coll = COLLECT(...)`

Comment: the "binaries" or "pathex" seems wrong here. At least it does not fix the issue with "lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll" ...

Comment: @Gaetan: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "the "binaries" or "pathex" seems wrong here".. files corrupt, missing, etc.. What exactly is woring in your situation? If its a new issue... post a new question and inculde your comment there. If its related to the path of files in case of OP I have only the information provided. Therefore its posted as an "example" how it should roughly be, as stated ;-)

Comment: I found the way to have it working. The "binaries" part here does actually nothing, since the loop that look for machine C runtime DLL uses the pathex. Solution is to add the relative path to the ucrt directories (both x86 and x64), the loop will only take the right ones. I have copied these small dlls directly in my project tree, it's only 5 Mb max so no need to bother install the full Windows 10 SDK to retrieve these dlls.

Answer (score 1):

I need to do this myself but haven't yet.  I'll try to post my full solution when I do.  In the mean time...

I think you may have to explicitly request they be included instead of just expanding the search path.

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-binary-files

Probably using the `Tree` class they mention to collect all the files for you.

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-tree-class

Answer (score 1):

I've seen PyInstaller and Py2exe fail to pickup dlls countless times.  Personally, I wrap my uses of them in batch or bash for a number of reasons to extend what they do.  Logically, I see an argument for wrapping them in py scripts themselves...

Anyway, it may be easier to just copy the dependencies into your installation package through a wrapper script rather then fight with this.

Typically, you'll get a dll missing error thrown at you when try to run something it's missing.  Add each one manually to the directory, noting what you needed to include yourself.  Then script that.