# Unable to run Kivy application compiled with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, runtime-error, kivy, pyinstaller

I am unable to run a Kivy application compiled with pyinstaller. Here is the output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\jakub\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-05-

11_28.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4885'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4885'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90522\kivy_install\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 140, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 899, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 291, in create_window
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1051, in create_window
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 758, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:12580)
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 538, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 734, in _set_filename
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 435, in load
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 201, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 41, in load

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
   File "site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
   File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
   File "site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
   File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
   File "site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
   File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
   File "site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
   File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
   File "site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
   File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
   File "site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
   File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
 SystemExit: 1
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_icon'
[11960] Failed to execute script main
```

This is my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\jakub\\Desktop\\python\\Datelbot'],
             binaries=[('img/icon.ico', 'img')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Datelbot.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True , version='version.py', icon='img\\icon.ico')
```

My `build.bat`:

```
pyinstaller^
--onefile^
--add-binary img/icon.ico;img^
--icon img/icon.ico^
--version-file version.py^
--name Datelbot.exe^
datelbot.exe.spec
```

And this is the PyInstaller output:

```
C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\python\Datelbot>pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary img/icon.ico;img --icon img/icon.ico --version-file version.py --name Datelbot.exe datelbot.exe.spec
92 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
92 INFO: Python: 3.6.5
93 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17666-SP0
94 INFO: UPX is not available.
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\jakub\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-05-11_32.txt
119 INFO: [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\jakub\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-05-11_32.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
116 INFO: [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
120 INFO: [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
123 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\jakub\\Desktop\\python\\Datelbot',
 'C:\\Users\\jakub\\Desktop\\python\\Datelbot']
123 INFO: checking Analysis
164 INFO: Building because C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\python\Datelbot\main.py changed
164 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
168 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
170 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5353 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
5356 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe
6973 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6982 INFO: Analyzing main.py
9667 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
11867 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
11868 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
17725 INFO: Loading module hooks...
17726 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
17741 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
17880 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-kivy.py"...
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
17918 INFO: [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\jakub\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-05-11_33.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\jakub\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-05-11_34.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Camera      ] Unable to find any valuable Camera provider.
opencv - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 45, in <module>
    import cv2

[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: winctypes
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4885'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4885'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[CRITICAL] [Spelling    ] Unable to find any valuable Spelling provider.
enchant - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enchant'
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\spelling\spelling_enchant.py", line 6, in <module>
    import enchant

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: null(['video_ffmpeg', 'video_ffpyplayer'] ignored)
28451 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
28468 INFO: Excluding import '_tkinter'
28487 INFO: Excluding import 'twisted'
28502 INFO:   Removing import of twisted.internet.error from module kivy.support
28502 INFO:   Removing import of twisted.internet from module kivy.support
28503 INFO:   Removing import of twisted.internet.reactor from module kivy.support
28503 INFO:   Removing import of twisted from module kivy.support
28503 INFO:   Removing import of twisted.internet._threadedselect from module kivy.support
28509 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-kivymd.py"...
28803 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
28827 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
29506 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
30153 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
30160 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
30166 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
30169 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
30175 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
30179 INFO:   Removing import of PySide.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
30180 INFO:   Removing import of PySide.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
30182 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
30182 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
30190 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
30198 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
30202 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
30202 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
31050 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
31213 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
31222 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pygments.py"...
33573 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide.py"...
33574 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide.QtCore.py"...
33697 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide.QtGui.py"...
34265 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
34633 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
35002 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
35053 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
35056 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
35836 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
35838 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
35839 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
35844 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
35951 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
36045 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
36235 INFO: checking Tree
36289 INFO: checking Tree
36309 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-docutils.py"...
38732 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
38890 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
38909 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
38917 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_twisted.py'
38919 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
38921 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
38924 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
38929 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_kivy.py'
38932 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_gstreamer.py'
38974 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries

79855 INFO: Looking for eggs
79855 INFO: Using Python library c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python36.dll
79857 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
79889 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\python\Datelbot\build\datelbot.exe\warndatelbot.exe.txt
80369 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\python\Datelbot\build\datelbot.exe\xref-datelbot.exe.html
80589 INFO: Appending 'binaries' from .spec
80606 INFO: checking PYZ
80621 INFO: Building because toc changed
80622 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\python\Datelbot\build\datelbot.exe\out00-PYZ.pyz
86657 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\python\Datelbot\build\datelbot.exe\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
86768 INFO: checking PKG
86785 INFO: Building because toc changed
86786 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
98225 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
98317 INFO: Bootloader c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
98318 INFO: checking EXE
98336 INFO: Building because toc changed
98337 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
98457 INFO: SRCPATH [('img\\icon.ico', None)]
98457 INFO: Updating icons from ['img\\icon.ico'] to C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx5kpyaoj
98460 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 20 bytes
98463 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 43720 bytes
98634 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\python\Datelbot\dist\Datelbot.exe
98878 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
```

*Note: The PyInstaller output also contains lot of warnings about dependencies (`.dll`, `.pyd`) such as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687975/pyinstaller-lib-not-found)*

I am using Windows 10 Insider Preview build, Python 3.6.5 and I have installed all the Kivy deps.

Comment: WIth AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_icon' as the error I believe we would need to know what object you're attempting to access 'set_icon' in.

Comment: It is the `kivy.core.window.Window`

Comment: Do you want me to add the code too?

Comment: I doubt I'll be able to help you if its internal to Kivy. The only suggestion I have based on what you've said is try accessing the Window later in your code, I've had issues that were helped by that with Kivy.

Comment: I tried placing the `Window.set_icon(...)` and `Window.set_title(...)` after `App` instance initialization, but before `App.run()` and now the last line of the error message is `[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.`

Comment: Couple things you should be aware of. None of the arguments in your `build.bat` have any effect. Most options are ignored when you specify a  `.spec` argument to `pyinstaller`. Have a look at the [Pyinstaller Documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html). Also, you don't need to set the `icon` or `name` yourself, `pyinstaller` does that for you.

Comment: You mean `title`? It only sets the icon of `exe` file not the window obviously. Same thing for title.